# vncviewer connect to primary display of lightdm on debian jessie (share with physical desktop)?

Tags: linux, debian, remote-desktop, vnc, lightdm

My server setup is: Debian jessie with lightdm DM with only modified changes section to sudo cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:

`[VNCServer]
enabled=true
command=Xvnc -rfbauth /home/abarik/.vnc/passwd
port=5900
listen-address=localhost
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
user-session=gnome
width=1024
height=768
depth=24`

I also have a desktop with primary monitor attached to it with default DM to lightdm.

My client setup: vnc client is vncviewer on mac (OS X)

How do I make sure that, if I VNC into the server from client, I reuse the primary physical display? If thats not possible, how do i keep atleast one of my virtual port `5900` active even after disconnecting?

Answer (score 1):

I think X11vnc is what you want.

X11vnc provides ability to connect your physical monitor.

For lightdm, you can use the following line.

`x11vnc -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/\:0`

If you want to run it constantly, you can add --loop flag like.

`x11vnc -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/\:0 --loop`